# Print / Log the SQLite Statement after the binding

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I like to log the compiled Statement after this:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {

    sqlite3_bind_int( compiledStatement, 1, updateThis.web_id);
    [...]

}
NSLog(@"Put out the complete SQLite Statement.");
```

The direct output failed, and i think this is not the way to do it:

```
NSLog(@"%@",compiledStatement);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't print the compiledStatement. What you can do is implement the [sqlite3_trace](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) callback function. This will print every executed sql statement.

To implement the function add this before your @implementation block

```
void sqliteCallbackFunc(void *foo, const char* statement) {
    NSLog(@"=> %s", statement);
}
```

This is the function you will point to.

To point to this function simple call:

`sqlite3_trace(db, sqliteCallbackFunc, NULL);`